# Постановка запятой перед союзом «и»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, ссп, и

*Я строю дом(,) и мне нужна помощь.*

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед союзом «и»?
Каким членом предложения является слово «нужна»?
Является ли данное предложение сложносочиненным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваше предложение сложносочиненное:

- подлежащее *Я* и сказуемое *строю*;
- подлежащее *помощь* и сказуемое *нужна*.

Согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §112. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится запятая.

Обобщающих элементов, из-за которых можно было бы не ставить запятую, в вашем предложении нет:

*Я строю дом, и мне нужна помощь.*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.